# While loop and reusing fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, while-loop

For a project I am building a flash game website, and I would like to know how to reuse this piece of code:

```
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT `category` FROM beoordeling");

                <?php
                echo "<div class='row list jumbotron'>";
                while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    echo "<div class='col-md-3'><a href='category.php?id=" . $data['category'] . "' class='thumbnail'><h4>" . ucfirst($data['category']) . " games</h4>";
                    echo "<img src='" . $imgLocation . $data['category'].".jpg' class='img-rounded' alt='" . $data['category'] . "' width='304' heigth='182'>";
                    echo "</a></div>";
                }
                echo "</div>";
            ?>
```

I need to be able to use the `$data['category']` again for dynamicly filling my menu with all of the games categories. If I just try to use the while loop again but then only one will work. The other one stays empty. Thanks alot!

Comment: just store it into another array!? like `$categories[] = $data['category']`

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but I'm a beginner with php, and I don't understand how that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set so that you could use it again. Make use of `mysqli_result::data_seek()` method for this.

Here's the reference:

- [`mysqli_result::data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT `category` FROM beoordeling");

    echo "<div class='row list jumbotron'>";
    while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<div class='col-md-3'><a href='category.php?id=" . $data['category'] . "' class='thumbnail'><h4>" . ucfirst($data['category']) . " games</h4>";
        echo "<img src='" . $imgLocation . $data['category'].".jpg' class='img-rounded' alt='" . $data['category'] . "' width='304' heigth='182'>";
        echo "</a></div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";

    // adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set
    $result->data_seek(0);

    // now you can use the result set again
    // for example, you can iterate through it using while loop again

?>
```